Is there a Windows equivalent of strndup?
Is there a native Windows C API call that does the same job as the BSD strndup() call?

The strndup() function copies at most n characters from the string s1, always NUL terminating the copied string.


It seems to be standartized in C23. See here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/strsafe/nf-strsafe-stringcchcopya

@wohlstad Which means Microsoft will make a big deal of pretending to appear to be trying to become more compliant with C23 - in about 2075.

@AndrewHenle could be :-) (but maybe gcc for Windows will support it sooner)

@wohlstad It already does - gcc 14 supports most of C23. The Mingw64 build can be downloaded from for example https://winlibs.com/.

@Lundin good to know. It makes my answer below more relevant ;-)

The POSIX Standard function strndup has finally made it along its more famous friend strdup into the C Standard as of the upcoming version (aka C23 or C2x)*.
Until your toolchain conforms to this version, which may take for ever, you can use a custom version in your programs, conforming to the same API and semantics, either using the standard name or a local one:
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t my_strnlen(const char *src, size_t n) {
    size_t len = 0;
    while (len < n && src[len])
        len++
    return len;
}

char *my_strndup(const char *s, size_t n) {
    size_t len = my_strnlen(s, n);
    char *p = malloc(len + 1);
    if (p) {
        memcpy(p, s, len);
        p[len] = '\0';
    }
    return p;
}


*) POSIX standard function strnlen did not get included for silly reasons, consistency did not suffice to counter the argument "can be emulated easily"

If you can use C23, you no longer need a Windows native function,
because the strndup function is a part of the standard from C23.
Requires  #include <string.h>:
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char * s = strndup("abcd", 3);
    printf("%s", s);
}

Output:
abc

Live demo

The problem is that the Microsoft C++ compiler has never made any attempt to conform to C standards, unless those standards are later taken up by C++ itself.

That's unforetunate. BTW - the OP actually didn't mention they are using MSVC. They could be using gcc for Windows (I would hope gcc will attempt to conform to the C standard sooner).

No they didn't mention which compiler they're using, but for Windows programming MSVC is pretty likely.

@MarkRansom I guess you are right. Although people who come from a Free BSD background might be different than the average user.

@MarkRansom Back in the days when I did Windows programming actively, I either used Mingw or Embarcadero. Both of these are still around and far more up to date than MSVC.

If you're on an older standard than C23 then you can use _strdup(). It's the equivalent to strdup and not the same as strndup so you'll have to do some adaptation, but it's the closest without writing the function on your own
In fact lots of POSIX extensions are available in MSVC with the _ prefix because the older names without _ have been deprecated due to C-standard conformance reasons although you can disable the warning and just use strdup instead

have been "deprecated" d̶u̶e̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶C̶-̶s̶t̶a̶n̶d̶a̶r̶d̶ ̶c̶o̶n̶f̶o̶r̶m̶a̶n̶c̶e̶ ̶r̶e̶a̶s̶o̶n̶s̶ because it's portable  FTFY.  The POSIX function read() comes from unistd.h which has nothing to do with the C standard, but it gets the same risible "deprecated" treatment.  And strcpy() and fopen() and many other functions also get the same treatment despite being required features in the C standard.  They all have one thing in common - they're portable while the MS-recommended replacement is not.

There isn't an equivalent to strndup.  The nearest you will get to strndup is StrDupA from shlwapi.h which behaves like strdup but not strndup.  There are also variants like

SHLocalStrDupA
SHStrDupA

And the W equivalents but nothing like strndup.  If you are sticking to MS, make sure you find out how to deallocate the memory when the program ends.  Many of these return PSTR.
